# Do probability predictions (predict_proba) from sklearn classifiers include the recall/precision

Tags: scikit-learn, logistic-regression

I've built a classifier using `sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression`, and when I make a new prediction, I also output the `predict_proba()` probability predictions. My question is, do these predictions include metrics for the goodness-of-fit of the model? For example, I like to output the `metrics.classification_report`, and was considering using the recall as a Bayesian prior to assess the probability output by `predict_proba()`, but if recall and precision are already factored into `predict_proba()`, then I don't want to double count.

I'd love to hear people's thoughts.

Comment: I am no expert in Naive bayes or gaussian process, but according to the [source of scikit naive bayes at github](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/master/sklearn/naive_bayes.py) it returns the exponent of `joint_log_likelihood()` of X, whatever it means. So IMO doesnt consider the recall. Hope it may be of some help

Comment: Why have you tagged logistic-regression when you are talking about Naive Bayes?

Comment: Vivek, I am using the LogisticRegression algorithm, not Naive Bayes, as the classifier. I only referenced Bayesian statistics because they can be used to combine the recall (a prior) with the predict_proba (measurement) to give a posterior probability.

Comment: Ahh. Sorry. My bad

Comment: `predict_proba` just returns the standard logistic regression probability (logit function of the input vector x coefficients, see  http://ufldl.stanford.edu/tutorial/supervised/LogisticRegression/) . There is no information about the goodness of fit or recall there..